# How Can I Publish Addons on the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, application-development

I have a commercial app, and according to the FAQ on http://developer.ubuntu.com, there is a way for me to publish add-ons as seen with many open source applications such as Thunderbird mail.

I am wondering how that is done. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @izx I don't have a paid subscription, commercial apps can be published for free. I have been bothering the member of the app review board who helps me far too much. I'm trying to give him a break.

Comment: I see, sorry about that. Comment deleted.

Comment: @izx No problem at all. I appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 3):

The "best" way would be for the original app to look for "add-on" data in a predetermined spot.

Then when you make an addon 'myapp-contentpack-a' it should have a dependency on 'myapp'.

Finally, when you start `myapp` it should just work.

Example:
FlashcardEngine installs to `/opt/com.aking1012/flashcardsEngine` with a subdirectory `./data/decks`.  A content pack would add decks in the `./data/decks` directory.

A more complex example is if you wanted to add a feature.  I'ld put that in the base package, but not have it "activate" unless another package is present.

Not the official answer, but it **IS** how I would do it

Comment: That would work, but how do developers get those add-on lists with the simple check box installation shown on the app page?

Comment: Good question.  I don't know that there's an "official" way.  I'ld either a)put my app add-on name (reasonably unique) in the keywords inside the desktop file or b)put a "check for add-ons" button in the app itself so I could open an apt-url from inside the app itself...bypassing what i didn't know how to do and fixing the problem anyway...